# How to make Minecraft send LAN advertise packets over Ethernet?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking

I have two computers, both of them have Minecraft on them.

Both computers are connected to the same Wi-Fi network, with `192.168.0.*` IPs which deliver communications over the airwaves.

Both computers are on a different floor from the router, but in physical proximity to each other. There are over twelve devices on this wireless network, and the router is not especially powerful; additionally, the computers' Wi-Fi adapters are reasonably dated.

So, I have connected the computers together via Ethernet and APIA, giving both computers `169.254.*.*` IPs which deliver communications over the Ethernet cable.

However, when a server is opened to LAN and does its broadcasting, it is broadcasting the `192.168.0.*` address, rather than the `169.254.*.*` one. Thus when the menu item is clicked, the connection is done over the (comparatively) slow, unstable wireless link rather than the reliable, low-latency Ethernet link.

### So, my question is this:

#### How can I make Minecraft broadcast the LAN server advertise packets over APIPA Ethernet in addition to (or even instead of) DHCP Wi-Fi?

I can manually look up and type in the Ethernet link-local IP and Minecraft's port, (this works,) but the port has to be changed every time Minecraft is restarted, and the IP has to be changed every time the computer is restarted: making this an unfeasible long-term solution (I'm trying to set it up for small children to use unsupervised.)

[I have discovered that](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1264112-mineannouncer-announce-any-server-as-a-lan-world?comment=6), to announce a LAN server, Minecraft simply sends a UDP broadcast packet containing `[MOTD]MinecraftWorldName[/MOTD][AD]25565[/AD]` to `224.0.2.60`, port 4445; but **how can I make Minecraft send these out the Ethernet port instead of, or in addition to, the Wi-Fi adapter?**

Comment: Does using direct connect with that IP address work?  (You'd also have to have the port which should be put in chat of the host)

Comment: @Oliver Yes, the connection is working fine, I can look up the `169.254.*.*` IP and punch in the port manually, and the connection goes through—however, the people who will be playing these LAN games are a bit young to be expected to go through with that. I'm trying to find a way to expedite playing LAN games over Ethernet.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude This is not in Minecraft's control. All Minecraft does is tell the Java implementation to open a socket on 0.0.0.0 (wildcard for any address it can find on the local network). You would have to find a way to make the Java implementation (which probably in turn relies on the OS) return the ethernet address.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a network configuration beyond the scope of minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to set the default network interface to be the wired one.
You can do this by giving it higher priority than the WiFi connection.

- Mac: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18458?locale=en_US
- Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2526067

Comment: Those answers control outbound (to internet) routing priority; I believe those are unrelated to UDP muticast interface ([which seems to lie entirely in the hands of the program](http://google.com/search?q=udp+multicast+specify+interface)…)

Additionally, I didn't splurge on Windows or OSX for these old scrap rigs, so I can't confirm it…